# Filter table by values in all columns

Tags: javascript

I have created search input that filters table values in first column.
How can I filter table values in all columns (except flag column)?

Search function code

```
function searchCountries() {
  let search = document.getElementById("search").value.toUpperCase();
  let tableRecord = document.getElementById("table");
  console.log(search);
  let tr = tableRecord.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    console.log(td);

    if (td) {
      let textvalue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

html structure

```
<tr>
   <td>${country.name}</td>
   <td>${country.currencies[0].name}</td>
   <td>${country.languages[0].name}</td>
   <td>${country.population}</td>
   <td>${country.area}</td>
   <td><img src='${country.flag}'></img></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to check all columns:

```js
function searchCountries() {
  let search = document.getElementById("search").value.toUpperCase();
  let tableRecord = document.getElementById("table");
  console.log(search);
  let tr = tableRecord.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let displayStyle = "none";
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (let j = 0; j < td.length - 1; ++j) {
      console.log(td[j]);

      if (td[j]) {
        let textvalue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
        if (textvalue.toUpperCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
          displayStyle = "";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    tr[i].style.display = displayStyle;
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input id="search">
<button onclick="searchCountries()">Search</button>
<table id="table">
<tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Currency</td>
   <td>Language</td>
   <td>Population</td>
   <td>Area</td>
   <td><img src=https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/04/13/12/flag-1179172_960_720.png></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Name 123</td>
   <td>Currency1</td>
   <td>Language</td>
   <td>Population</td>
   <td>Area</td>
   <td><img src=https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/04/13/12/flag-1179172_960_720.png></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank You. I wan to know if the question was unclear? Cause someone voted down and now I can't ask any question. Thanks in advanced for the answear.